# How can I select the highest counts attributes from different groups?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have a table with players data(name, team, etc..) and a table with goals (player who scored it, local team, etc...). What I need to do is, get from each team the highest scorer. So the result I'm getting is something like:

- germany - whatever name - 1
- germany - another dude - 5
- spain - another name - 8
- italy - one more name - 6

As you can see teams repeat, and I want them not to, just get the highest scorer of each team.

Right now I have this:

```
SELECT  P.TEAM_PLAYER, G.PLAYER_GOAL, COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL GOALS" FROM PLAYER P, GOAL G
WHERE TO_CHAR(G.DATE_GOAL, 'YYYY')=2002
AND P.NAME = G.PLAYER_GOAL
GROUP BY G.PLAYER_GOAL, P.TEAM_PLAYER
HAVING COUNT(*)>=ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PLAYER P2 where P.TEAM_PLAYER = P2.TEAM_PLAYER GROUP BY P2.TEAM_PLAYER)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

I am 100% sure I'm close, and I'm pretty sure I have to do this with the HAVING feature, but I can't get it right.

Without the HAVING it returns a list of all the players, their teams and how many goals have they scored, now I want to cut it down to only one player for each team.

PD: the teams in the table GOAL are local and visiting team, so I have to use the Player table to get the team. Also the Goal table is not a list of the players and how many goals they have scored, but a list of every individual goal and the player who scored it.

Comment: You appear to be using Oracle and not MySQL, so I tagged accordingly.

Comment: True, sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can try this query.

just get `MAX` of `PLAYER_GOAL` column,`SUM(G.PLAYER_GOAL)` instead of  `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT  P.TEAM_PLAYER, 
        MAX(G.PLAYER_GOAL) "PLAYER_GOAL", 
        SUM(G.PLAYER_GOAL) AS "TOTAL GOALS" 
FROM PLAYER P 
INNER JOIN GOAL G 
ON P.NAME = G.PLAYER_NAME
WHERE TO_CHAR(G.DATE_GOAL, 'YYYY')=2002
GROUP BY P.TEAM_PLAYER
ORDER BY SUM(G.PLAYER_GOAL) DESC;
```

NOTE :

- Avoid using commas to `join` tables it's a old `join` style, You can use inner-join instead.

**Edit**

I don't know your table schema, but this query might be work.

use a subquery to contain your current result set. then get `MAX` function and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT T.TEAM_PLAYER,
            T.PLAYER_GOAL,
            MAX(TOTAL_GOALS) AS "TOTAL GOALS"
FROM 
(
    SELECT  P.TEAM_PLAYER, G.PLAYER_GOAL, COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL_GOALS" FROM 
    PLAYER P, GOAL G
    WHERE TO_CHAR(G.DATE_GOAL, 'YYYY')=2002
    AND P.NAME = G.PLAYER_GOAL
    GROUP BY G.PLAYER_GOAL, P.TEAM_PLAYER
    HAVING COUNT(*)>=ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PLAYER P2 where P.TEAM_PLAYER = P2.TEAM_PLAYER GROUP BY P2.TEAM_PLAYER)
) T
GROUP BY T.TEAM_PLAYER,
         T.PLAYER_GOAL
ORDER BY MAX(TOTAL_GOALS) DESC
```

Comment: This groups all the goals of each team into one single player.
That's it, with my query Ronaldo gets 8 goals, and doing yours he gets 18.

Comment: OK!! Could you provide some data from your tables and your expected result?

Comment: Sure!! Writing the code above without the HAVING line gives me: 

(Brasil - Ronaldo - 8)
(Brasil - Rivaldo - 6)
(Italy - Whatever - 5)
(Italy - another - 4)

Now as you can see teams repeat, I want them not to.

I'm using two tables: the table Player get's me the team of the player, and the table goal that gives me the player that scored and the number of goals. The date of the goal is used to search for a specific tournament but nothing else.

Also, in the table goal you don't have a player and the number of goals scored, but the goals one by one and who scored them.

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem is Player_goal is not a number, but the name of the player who scored.

Also I'm checking the page you mentioned and I'm trying to use it to get you a better grasp of the situation, but it's my first time and it's costing me a little.

Anyway lots of thanks for the help!!

Comment: @linkfix I use another way you can try it.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are trying to do there. It just gives me an error after the `) AS T` but I'll look into it

Comment: @linkfix Remove `T` instead of `AS T`

Comment: Ok I'm having problems with the Total_goals now as it's an invalid identifier but I feel bad for asking this much so I'll look into it

Thank you very much for real!!!

Comment: @linkfix the problem is on alias name  `TOTAL GOALS` of subquery,I edit my answer.